# How to reference/source a custom .vimrc file

Tags: vim

Is there a way to reference (or "source") another user's .vimrc file?

When I `kuu` (a variant of `su` that uses kerberos security tokens) to an admin user ID, I would like to use my personal `.vimrc` file.

I don't want to overwrite the admin's existing `.vimrc` file because the admin ID is shared by multiple users.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `MYVIMRC` environment variable. This way, you won't have to pass `-u` each time you fire up vim. (You can of course do an alias instead, but that won't help with e.g., `vipw`)

Keep in mind that `.vimrc` can execute arbitrary commands, if you use `/home/user/.vimrc` you may be creating a security issue (e.g., someone manages to compromise your user account, changes your .vimrc, and then gets root the next time you edit a file as root). You can, of course, keep a known-safe copy in `~root/` somewhere.

You could assumably even set something up in `~root/.bashrc` to automatically set `MYVIMRC` to something different for each different administrator.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's just what I asked.  And I also appreciate the security warnings.

Comment: @Ruslan well, the question is about a *.vim*rc file, so... It won't work for EMACS either. Or joe, or nano, or Microsoft Word. (And if you call vim as `vi`, then you're asking it to run in compatibility mode) [I'm probably misunderstanding what you're trying to say; please clarify.]

Comment: vi also uses .vimrc. so I guess my comment is valid - author of the topic didn't specify if he is using vi or vim or both. 
ps. on some of the systems vi is linked to vim actually.

Comment: @Ruslan *vi* does not use .vimrc. [vi](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/) is a completely separate program than vim, which reads `~/.exrc`. There are also the relatively popular nvi and elvis clones; neither of them read `.vimrc`. Often, a version of `vim` is installed (or symlinked) to `vi` (and which you'd use `$EXINIT` to override). Though it actually still works fine, *unless* you have it symlinked to `vim.tiny` (a version of Vim built to be as small file size as possible), which ignores `$MYVIMRC` no matter what name you call it under.

Comment: **Disclaimer:** In current versions of Vim, the `MYVIMRC` environmental variable is ***not*** read. Vim only ***sets*** it (if `vimrc` file has been found in one of hardcoded, specified locations, see `:h .vimrc`)

Answer (score 32):

Try `-u` parameter and specify a path to an alternative configuration file.

For example: `vim -u /home/jesse/myvimrc`

See http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html

Comment: Not quite unfortunately. `man -u`: `-u {vimrc}  Use the commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations`. Sounds good so far, but it also puts vim in a special mode which `All the other initializations are skipped.` This caused hard to debug problems for me which I tracked down to `vim -u ~/vimrc` not being equivalent to `vim`. What worked for me was: `vim -u <(echo source /usr/share/vim/vimrc; cat ~/.vimrc)` using the bash shell specific `<(...)` capture.

Answer (score 7):

Use an alternate .vimrc file without plugins as mentioned, and add an alias in .bash_profile or something.

```
alias svim='vim -u ~/.vimrc_simple'
```

Really I prefer the following:

```
alias vvim='vim -u ~/.vimrc_vundle'
```

In order to keep `vim` as a lightweight command, as plugin loading seems to slow down program instantiation.

Answer (score 6):

In vim:

`:source /path/to/your/.vimrc`

Comment: It's not enough: the &rtp is not updated this way -- well, of course the .vimrc could reset the &rtp.

Answer (score 4):

I've only ever attempted this a few times and this seems to work fine for me.  Define an alias for vim that is something like the following:

```
alias vim="HOME=~yournormaluser vim -c 'let \$HOME = \"$HOME\"'"
```

What this does is trick vim into using your `$HOME/.vim/` environment, yet resets `$HOME` from within vim so doing things like `:e ~/something.txt` will still use the admin user's `$HOME`.

This has the added advantage that you don't have to change the admin's `~/.vimrc` at all.

Comment: Then again, this would alias vim for everyone who uses that admin user.  When I've done this in the past I was in a situation where my environment was aware I was su'ing from my `$USER` and sourced `~$USER/.aliases` so I could get away with this.  Maybe you can still use this information somehow.

Comment: add a randy_gvim alias, something the others are unlikely to use.

Comment: Sourcing $USER/.aliases probably creates a security hole. See the note in my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @derobert: Indeed.  In my case the 'admin' account was actually just a shared user account.  For simply editing as root with an altered environment I'd almost always suggest `sudo -e` or `sudoedit`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your initial owner owns your tty. If so, you can get your initial USER with:

```
stat -c'%U' `tty`
```

By placing your customized root .vimrc in /root/.vimrc.$USRNAME you can keep a reasonably secure customized vimrc file. You can do other things too, but I leave that to your imagination.

Method 1 - put this in your /root/.bashrc & smoke it:

```
# Source a custome vimrc if it exists
mytty=`tty`
initial_user=`stat -c'%U' $mytty`
custom_vimrc="/root/.vimrc.$initial_user"
if [ -f $custom_vimrc ]; then
    export VIMINIT="source $custom_vimrc"
fi
```

Method 2 - put something similar in your /root/.vimrc (a better solution since you might use ksh).

If anyone can figure out Method 2, I'd welcome the post. I lack motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I just symlink Root's .vimrc's to mine. From BASH (as root):

`ln -s /home/<me>/.vimrc /root/.vimrc`

But you do need to be careful about what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 - as an addition to .vimrc

tried different things
`tty` does not work, and `system("who am i")` neither (they come up empty when used from within vim-function), so this way is much longer. Any shortcuts are welcome

```
"Local .vimrc for the user
" 1. get the user, which used su
" 2. we can load his .vimrc.<user>
" from $HOME (from where we have sudo'ed in)
let b:term = substitute( system ("ps T | grep ' ps T$' | sed -e 's/^  *//' | cut -d ' ' -f 2 "), "\n", "", "" )
let b:user = substitute( system ("who | grep ".b:term." | cut -d ' ' -f 1 "), "\n", "", "" )
let b:file = $HOME."/.vimrc.".b:user
if filereadable(b:file)
  execute 'source '.b:file
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a plugin years ago since I wanted my own `.vimrc` on our servers without forcing any user who uses sudo to navigate as root to my `.vimrc`.

My plugin works exactly as the plugin what @ULick provided.

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/boesing/f14156a732e697e2b0389396c956da76)