# Install multiple version of Vim, and make each use different .vimrc file, respectively

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu

Make it on Linux. The reason to use more than one version of Vim, is because one version would be heavily hacked, for Lisp jobs.  I want separate it and make it use it's own .vimrc file as well.

```
/usr/bin/vim   use -> ~/.vimrc
/my/vim        use -> ..../another_vimrc
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618151/how-to-reference-source-a-custom-vimrc-file

Comment: If I assume that you are able to hack vim, just change the name of the `.vimrc` file in this hack. A simple `perl -pi -e 's/\.vimrc/.vhack/g' /my/vim` should work fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Command line option

You can give the `-u` parameter to your command line. This parameter will force the vim to read the specific vimrc without reading the system wide configurations:

```
/my/vim -u /path/another_vimrc
```

You can even create a command alias, with which you can start this custom vim. Put this in your `.bash_profile` for e.g.:

```
alias customvim /my/vim -u /path/another_vimrc
```

And then start this custom vim with:

```
customvim
```

#### Building configuration

You can specify the `prefix` option to the configuration script of when you're building from source. If you set this, vim will look for configuration file in the prefixed directory.

For e.g. if you do with [stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3/ && make install
```

Then the vim will be installed in `/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3/` and the custom configuration should be in `/usr/local/stow/vim-7.3/etc/vimrc`

Comment: This is nice. I found one addition configuration to do for the separated Vim, in the another_vimrc file:  set rtp=/another/vim/runtime/path,$VIMRUNTIME,...,  This make it use another runtimepath

Comment: What if you want to change the binary name (ie. `super-kick-ass-vim`) but not the location (ie. `/usr/bin`)

Comment: You can easily create a symlink for that or as I suggested alias it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `Predefined Vim variables(v:version)`.
Suppose you have installed both `vim6` and `vim7`, you can create two `.vimrc_X` files:

```
~/.vimrc_6
~/.vimrc_7
```

Then you create another `.vimrc` file:

```
~/.vimrc
```

which contains:

```
if v:version >=700
    source ~/.vimrc_7
elseif v:version >=600
    source ~/.vimrc_6
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Vim filetype plugin (search for ftplugin), it allows you to specify a configuration for given filetype.