# Options for .vimrc from command-line arguments?

Tags: vim

I have a custom .vimrc file which I use across many different machines.

Some machines are less powerful than others, and it would be nice to be able to load a "stripped-down" version of the .vimrc file.  However, I'd like to maintain a single .vimrc to avoid fragmentation.

Ideally, I'd like to pass arguments to my .vimrc from the command line. If the "minimal" option is selected, the .vimrc would skip over loading the most resource-intensive plugins.

Does anyone know the best/cleanest way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit: The slower machine I'm talking about is a Raspberry Pi over SSH.  Vim itself isn't slow, although I have several plugins including NERDTree and Syntastic that take lots of time to load on the Pi's limited CPU.  By taking out most plugins for my "minimal" configuration, I cut down the loading time from 3.5 seconds to 0.5 seconds.

Comment: "Some machines are less powerful than others..." _(How much power does **Vim** really need? ;)_

Comment: I have an idea. read /proc/xxx to get cpu info, memory, available memory, cpu load etc. then decide to load which vim config. It could be done with vimscript (with the support of external command) or other language/scripts, as a wrapper of your vim start script. this is doable however...@summea 's comment is nice!

Comment: I accidentally tagged this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618151/how-to-reference-source-a-custom-vimrc-file - it isn't quite a dupe but you might find that question useful

Comment: I would be curious about what parts of one's vimrc could require more power than others.

Comment: The slower machine I'm talking about is a Raspberry Pi over SSH. Vim itself isn't slow, although I have several plugins including NERDTree and Syntastic that take lots of time to load on the Pi's limited CPU. By taking out most plugins for my "minimal" configuration, I cut down the loading time from 3.5 seconds to 0.5 seconds.

Comment: @Bill Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `--cmd` switch to execute a command before any VIMRC is loaded.

So on your less powerful machines you could alias `vim` to something like `vim --cmd 'let weak=1'` and then in your `$VIMRC` you can say:

```
if exists('weak')
  echo "poor machine"
endif
```

Comment: You could set up an alias for this: `alias vim='vim --cmd "let weak=1"'` in your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

take a look at source:

```
source /foo/bar/another_vimrc
```

Your 'heavy' vimrc can just source the basic vimrc and add what you want. This is also really handy for project/machine specific abbreviations, ctags, etc.

Comment: That's how I do it. Different local file on every machine. Here's the last line of my `~/.vimrc`: `if filereadable(expand('~/.vim-local/vimrc-local')) | source ~/.vim-local/vimrc-local | endif`. I could do more complex things with `~/vimrc-local/after` files and some `runtimepath` manipulation, but so far things are working fine with a single local file.

Answer (score 4):

This will not keep a single vimrc file, but for the sake of others who have the same question (as stated at the top of the page):

```
$ vim -u ~/.vim-min.vim
```

Note that this will suppress loading both the system vimrc file (if any) and your personal vimrc file.

```
:help -u
:help startup
```

(See Step 3 of the second reference.)

Answer (score 0):

From the excellent answers above, I got this working:

~/.vimrc :

```
if exists('FLAG')       " 'FLAG' passed from ~/.bashrc 'vimm' alias
    set textwidth=150   " (launches vim in expanded terminal window)
    set lines=58
else
    set textwidth=79
    set lines=40
endif
```

~/.bashrc :

```
# Needed to combine following two lines for ~/.vimrc use:
#   alias vimm='konsole --geometry 1900x1040+0+0 -e "bash -c \"vim\""; exit'
#   vim --cmd 'let FLAG=1'
str="'let FLAG=1'"
alias vimm='konsole --geometry 1900x1040+0+0 -e "bash -c \"vim --cmd $str\""; exit'
```

Now, 'vim' (normal use) launches Vim in a normal-sized terminal, whereas 'vimm' launches Vim in a larger terminal (alternate settings).

'Konsole' is the terminal that I use in Arch Linux.