# Bulk file re-formatting for "cpp" files with VIM

Tags: c++, regex, batch-file, vim

I have a number of large projects consisting of several `.cpp` and `.h` files. The indentation styles are a mess (hard-tab, spaces, and every possible mix of them), trailing whitespace at end-of-line, line-ending consolidation. I can currently resolve all these issues in VIM by opening a file, and issuing the following commands:

- `:%s/^M//g`  (`^M` generated via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>; Handles deleting Windows-style line-endings).
- `:%s/\s\+$//g` (Delete trailing whitespace at end-of-lines).
- `gg=G` (Auto-reindent the file using my current `.VIMRC` settings).

How could I run the above commands in batch mode? My best solution so far is to create a custom `.VIMRC` that runs the above commands and exits VIM when done, [like in various SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618151/how-to-reference-source-a-custom-vimrc-file). However, this sometimes fails due to searches failing to find a match, and the automation script then fails.

Is there a more robust approach than custom `.VIMRC` files, such as a string of commands passed directly at the command line to VIM?

Comment: Maybe take a look at `sed`?

Comment: @Galik `sed` works on lines of text. It's not capable of re-indenting blocks of code AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run everything on the command line you can use the following.

```
vim -c 'argdo set ff=unix | %s/\s\+$//ge | normal gg=G' -c 'wqa' <list of files>
```

vim can take normal mode commands with `-c`. I used `argdo` to run `set ff=unix | %s/\s\+$//ge | normal gg=G` on every argument provided to vim. I used `set ff=unix` instead of `:%s/^M//g` since you are asking to change the file format to have unix line endings. (You could also just run `dos2unix` on all the files.) Next `%s/\s\+$//ge` is run on the whole buffer removing trailing whitespace. The `e` flag is necessary just incase there isn't any trailing whitespace. Lastly `normal gg=G` runs `gg=G` in normal mode.

After `argdo` is done we run `wqa` which saves and quits all the files.

(If you actually have carriage returns in the file and you can use `:%s/\r//ge` to remove them instead of `set ff=unix`)

Comment: Something similar could just be added to a function in a vim script and loaded up as necessary. Then you wouldn't need to remember the "magic incantation," you could just call that function (from the command line, even).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you not take a Vim-only approach to this, unless:

- you're going to be the only developer on “a number of large projects”, or
- you can get every other developer to start using your new shared `.vimrc`.

A better approach is to **establish coding/editing standards and codify them into your VCS’s commit hooks**.

A tool for this is the oldie-but-goodie `indent` (see its man page). You can create a `.indent.pro` file that can be shared to enforce a shared style. The Ruby project appears to [enforce style this way](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/.indent.pro). Note that its support for C++ may be insufficient for some of your needs.

For starters, you’d want to pick the styles you think are superior, and then run `indent` recursively across the projects.